# How to change the URL in browser due to the navigation at iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, iframe

I want to change the URL in browser based on the iframe navigation like:

```
**[URL at navigator: http://localhost/]**

<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://localhost/?loadiframe=true">
   <!-- this is at the code retrieved by the iframe -->
   <a id="mypage" href="http://localhost/mypage/?loadiframe=true">Navi</a>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks the #mypage link the URL in the browser will be:

```
http://localhost/mypage/
```

Not matters that the src of the iframe be the same always.

¿Is that possible?

Maybe using ajax.........??

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: [Html5 history api](http://html5demos.com/history)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `target` attribute of the link to `_parent`, the address should open in the parent window:

```
<a id="mypage" href="http://localhost/mypage/?loadiframe=true" target="_parent">Navi</a>
```